# Complex CSS layout – flexbox or grid?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

I'm looking to achieve a complex layout (see Figures 1-4 below) where I have three main elements: title, side element, and tags. The title should span the entire width, the side element should float to the right and span the entire height of the container, and then the tags (which there could be many) should wrap under the title.

```
 ___________________________   ____
|                           | |    |
|   lorem ipsum dolor ...   | |    |
|___________________________| |    |
 ______   _______   ______    | XX |
|      | |       | |      |   |    |
|  ab  | |  cde  | |  fg  |   |    |
|______| |_______| |______|   |____|
```

**Prerequisites:**

1. The `.title` should be as **wide** as possible
2. The `.side` and `.tag`'s should be only as wide as their content, so as **narrow** as possible.
3. Sizes of any of the elements are unknown, thus I **can't use fixed widths or percentages** (except 100% obviously).
4. The solution should work at any container width.
5. `.side` and `.tag`'s are **optional**, so the solution should work if they are missing.
6. All element are siblings, meaning **I can't wrap all `.tag`'s in a `div`**, for example.
7. The `.side` element always comes last in the source code, hence the `order` property below.

Please see the use cases that I'm looking to cover:

- [Figure 1: Title, side element, and a few tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H1GQ.png)
- [Figure 2: Title, side element, and more tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1ASm.png)
- [Figure 3: Only title and a couple of tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrVuC.png)
- [Figure 4: Only title and the side element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92NUM.png)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.title {
  order: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.side, .tag {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
.side {
  order: 2;
}
.tag {
  order: 3;
}

/* sample styling - ignore */
.container { width: 100%; }
.title, .tag, .side { padding: 30px; margin: 5px; color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 24px; }
.title { background: coral; }
.tag { background: cornflowerblue; }
.side { background: mediumseagreen; }
```

```html
<h2>Case 1</h2>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
  <div class='tag'>abc</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='side'>XX</div>
</div>

<h2>Case 2</h2>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
  <div class='tag'>abc</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>jkl</div>
  <div class='tag'>mno</div>
  <div class='tag'>pqr</div>
  <div class='side'>XX</div>
</div>

<h2>Case 3</h2>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
  <div class='tag'>abc</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
</div>

<h2>Case 4</h2>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
  <div class='side'>XX</div>
</div>
```

**My question**

What is the best way to achieve this complex flexible layout? Can I use flexbox to make all of the use cases above functional, or should I look more into grid?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt flexbox can fill all the requirements.

Here is a CSS grid approximation with few drawbacks:

- all the tags will have the same width and the width is controlled by the container not their content
- If the side element is missing we will have an empty cell (working to find a solution for this)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  border:1px solid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,minmax(100px,1fr));
}

.title {
  grid-column:1 / -2;
}

.title + .tag {
  grid-column:1;
}

.side {
  grid-column:-2;
  grid-row: 1/span 1000;
}


/* sample styling - ignore */

.title,
.tag,
.side {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.title {
  background: coral;
}

.tag {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.side {
  background: mediumseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
  <div class='side'>XX</div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
  <div class='tag'>abc</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>gh</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='side'>XX</div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
  <div class='tag'>abc</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
</div>
```

As per the comment here is a solution where the side element will take only one row:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  border:1px solid;
}

.title {
  order:-2;
  flex-grow:1;
  flex-basis:0;
  min-width:0;
}


.side {
  order:-1;
}
.container:before {
  content:"";
  flex-basis:100%;
}

/* sample styling - ignore */

.title,
.tag,
.side {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.title {
  background: coral;
}

.tag {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.side {
  background: mediumseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
  <div class='side'>XX</div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
  <div class='tag'>abc</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>gh</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='side'>XX XX</div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
  <div class='tag'>abc</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
</div>
```

---

Since I think CSS alone cannot achieve this, here is a JS solution:

```js
var cs = document.querySelectorAll('.container');

cs.forEach((a) => {
  var side = a.querySelector('.side');
  if(side)
    a.style.paddingRight = (side.offsetWidth + 10) + "px";
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  border:1px solid;
  padding-right: 0px;
  position:relative;
}

.title {
  flex-basis:100%;
}

.side {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}

/* sample styling - ignore */

.title,
.tag,
.side {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.title {
  background: coral;
}

.tag {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.side {
  background: mediumseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
  <div class='side'>XX</div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
  <div class='tag'>abc</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>gh</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='side'>XX XX</div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
  <div class='tag'>abc</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
  <div class='tag'>def</div>
  <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make all columns shrink to fit their content **but** the title? Unfortunately tags can have various lengths of content (e.g. 4 vs 16 characters long) so I'm not sure I can make them all the same width...

Comment: @philfriday not possible with CSS grid. The only way to do what you want require some JS. a little script can help having all the requirements if you are ok with this?

Comment: Sorry, trying to refrain from using JS for this one... Hear this out: if the side element only spanned one row vertically, could I use flexbox for this, considering all other variables are the same? That means, the first row would be the title and side element (XX), and the second row is all the tags.

Comment: @philfriday yes that one is easy: https://jsfiddle.net/brjpz4L3/

Comment: Thanks @Temani Afif, that looks great! Is there a way to prevent the XX element from wrapping when you shrink the viewport? I would like to make it stay in the first row always.

Comment: Thanks so much @Temani Afif, I think this should do the trick for me.

Comment: @philfriday should I update my answer with this solution then?

Answer (score -1):

I changed the HTML and this is my solution, please check.
Hope this help :)

```css
.container {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .title {
            order: 1;
            flex-grow: 1;
            flex-basis: 100%;
        }
        .side, .tag {
            flex-grow: 0;
            flex-basis: auto;
        }
        .side {
            order: 2;
        }
        .tag {
            order: 3;
        }
        .content-page {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .content-tags {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        /* sample styling - ignore */
        .container { width: 100%; }
        .title, .tag, .side { padding: 30px; margin: 5px; color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 24px; }
        .title { background: coral; }
        .tag { background: cornflowerblue; }
        .side { background: mediumseagreen; }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class="content-page">
        <div class='title'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
        </div>
        <div class="content-tags">
            <div class='tag'>abc</div>
            <div class='tag'>def</div>
            <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
            <div class='tag'>def</div>
            <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
            <div class='tag'>abc</div>
            <div class='tag'>def</div>
            <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
            <div class='tag'>def</div>
            <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
            <div class='tag'>def</div>
            <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
            <div class='tag'>def</div>
            <div class='tag'>ghi</div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class='side'>XX</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I can't change the HTML markup and put tags in their own `div`...